# I have the HTTP put class and when I insert/update using postman and remove revunue date from json I get an error nullpointer exception

Tags: apex, http, postman

```
global with Sharing class ContractHeadersRESTAPI{

@HttpPut
    global static String ContractHeaderUpdate(String Name, String ContractName,String Type,String EndDate, String ExternalID,String LetterofCommitment,String PortfolioExecutive,boolean Primary,String ProductSegment,String RevenueEndDate,String StartDate,String Status,String Vendor,String VendorID,Id ContractRecordType)
    {
   
        Contract_Header__c conhead = New Contract_Header__c();
        conhead.Name = Name;
        conhead.Contract_Name__c = ContractName;
        conhead.Type__c= Type;
        conhead.End_Date__c = Date.parse(EndDate);
        conhead.External_ID_Contract_ID__c = ExternalID;
        conhead.Letter_of_Commitment__c = LetterofCommitment;
        conhead.Portfolio_Exec_PE__c = PortfolioExecutive;
        conhead.Primary__c = Primary;
        conhead.Product_Segment__c = ProductSegment;
        conhead.Revenue_End_Date__c = Date.parse(RevenueEndDate);
        conhead.Start_Date__c = Date.parse(StartDate);
        conhead.Status__c= Status;
        conhead.Vendor__c= Vendor;
        conhead.Vendor_ID__c= VendorID;
        conhead.Recordtypeid = ContractRecordType;
       
        upsert conhead External_ID_Contract_ID__c ;
        return conhead.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check if Revenue Date is a required field.

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect to happen when this data is not provided or is `null`?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. Many of the library methods that do parsing do not like null parameters. You'll either want to use a try-catch block, or use an if statement.

```
if(RevenueEndDate != null) {
    conhead.Revenue_End_Date__c = Date.parse(RevenueEndDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its coming because of Date.parse()

you can use following code to prevent from this exception

```
if(String.isNotBlank(RevenueEndDate)){
 conhead.Revenue_End_Date__c = Date.parse(RevenueEndDate);
}
```